# gnuplot script name OR bash $0 alternative for gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

How to programmatically get the name of current gnuplot script? I know that I can call gnuplot script from bash and get it file name but I am wondering if it is possible from inside gnuplot. My goal is to make something like:

```
date=system("date +%F_%T | sed 's/:/-/g'")
my_name=$0 # THIS IS HOW TO DO IT IN BASH

set term png
set output my_name.date.".png"
```

I've tried:

```
my_name=system("cat /proc/$$/cmdline")
```

but it returned sh instead of script name

Comment: The `sh` you got is the command line of the system call, not your script. Also, this question seems to have nothing to do with bash.

Comment: Bash was used just as example language where it is possible to demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: That doesn't make it a bash question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite an answer to your question, but this might help with what you want to do:

You can leave `my_name` unset in the script, and set it either inside gnuplot, just before you load the script (where you need to know the script name anyway):

```
my_name=...
load(my_name)
```

or set it when you invoke `gnuplot` from the shell:

```
$ gnuplot -e "my_name=${FILE}" ${FILE}
```

A few more things:

```
date=system("date +%F_%T | sed 's/:/-/g'")
```

can be replaced with

```
date=system("date +%F_%H-%M-%S")
```

(which is shorter and doesn't need to be parsed through `sed`) or without any forking at all:

```
date=strftime("%F_%H-%M-%S",time(0.0))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using gnuplot version 5 you have access to the file called with `load` via the variable `ARG0`

Consider the script `test.gp` which contains only

```
print ARG0
```

Now, calling this with

```
gnuplot -e "load 'test.gp'"
```

prints you `test.gp` on the screen. With earlier versions you don't have access to a similar variable (also not when using `call`). For earlier versions you must stick to one of the solutions given by @chw21

Comment: I was hoping that gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 0 can do it also

Comment: With `gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 8` I was able to use `ARG0` without `load` just by `gnuplot plot_file_name.plt`.